# Generar un grid con un div que ocupe más de una fila en Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4, angular

Estaba utilizando una versión 3 de Bootstrap. Ahora que actualicé a la versión 4 tengo el siguiente problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me funcionaba con Bootstrap 3 (**ver en página completa**):

```css
.titulo {
  height: 200px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.dato {
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="titulo col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">Titulo</div>

  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">2</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">3</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">4</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">5</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">6</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">7</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">8</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">9</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">10</div>
</div>
```

Y el mismo código me dejó de funcionar con Bootstrap 4:

```css
.titulo {
  height: 200px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.dato {
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="titulo col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">Titulo</div>

  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">2</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">3</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">4</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">5</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">6</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">7</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">8</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">9</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">10</div>
</div>
```

**Pregunta:**
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el div `.titulo` ocupe 2 filas, y los divs `.dato` se acomoden de forma responsiva, utilizando el espacio restante, de acuerdo a si es un dispositivo `sm` o `lg`? Los divs tienen un alto fijo (el título es 2 veces el alto del resto).

---

Vale aclarar que armo las cajas pequeñas dinámicamente con un `ngFor` de angular, por lo tanto dividirlas dentro de contenedores de forma fija no es una opción. El código que tengo para generarlas es:

```
<div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" 
*ngFor="let dato of datos">
    {{dato.nombre}}
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con esta herramienta? https://www.prepbootstrap.com/converter

Comment: El tamaño de esas cajas sera fijo o relativo? Por que si es fijo, seria que agregaras la caja grande en un contenedor, luego las otras 2 filas de cajas pequeñas en otro contenedor y todo esto dentro de un contenedor mucho mas grande.

Comment: El ancho de esas cajas lo maneja bootstrap, lo que si es fijo es el alto.
Antes funcionaba bien, con una version antigua de boostrap, pero ahora que utilizo la ultima versión, las cajas pequeñas ya no fluyen al rededor de la caja mas grande

Comment: Hola Carlos, talves podríamos darte una mejor respuesta si nos muestras el html "compilado", te sugiero que termines el [tour] del sitio y **revises** como crear un [mcve]

Comment: Hola KacosPro, acabo de editar mi pregunta y subí un fragmento de código en donde trato de explicar el problema, espero se vea y se comprenda esta vez. De ante mano gracias
Aunque no se si en este fragmento de código ustedes puedan modificar el código para ver el resultado al cambiar de versión de bootstrap

Comment: Pues en ese fragmento de código muestro el resultado correcto con la versión 3.3.7 y lo que yo quiero es que salga lo mismo pero con la versión ultima de bootstrap (si cambian la versión y ejecutan verán que hay diferencia)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Antes que nada, quiero aclarar que no conozco Angular, y asumo por lo que dice el OP que la estructura del HTML generado **no se puede modificar** por algún motivo.

El problema en este caso y por el cual no funciona el código con Bootstrap 4 (pero sí con Bootstrap 3), es porque la versión 4 utiliza flexbox para generar sus layouts de grillas, mientras la versión 3 utiliza el típico y antiguo esquema de `float: left` con elementos de bloque.

Flexbox es un Box Module de CSS que fue diseñado para generar layouts **unidimensionales**, o sea, en una sola dirección, bien sea columnas o filas.

En este caso se intenta generar un layout bidimensional, lo cual lo convierte una grilla y por lo cual Flexbox "se queda corto". Para eso existen las Grillas de CSS. [Ver ejemplos básicos de grillas](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/).

Hay muchas soluciones a este problema, y teniendo en cuenta que no hay una flexibilidad a nivel de HTML ni del framework CSS utilizado, hay que plantear una solución que **personalmente no prefiero, ni me parece la más adecuada o "limpia"**.

Mi solución consiste en retroceder y "emular" el comportamiento de Bootstrap 3 para esta "grilla" específica, devolviendo el contenedor `.row` a que sea un bloque (y no un contenedor de flexbox), y haciendo que las columnas de dicho "row" utilicen `float: left;`

```css
.titulo {
  height: 200px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.dato {
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.row {
  display: block !important;
}

[class*="col-md-"] {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="titulo col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">Titulo</div>

  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">2</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">3</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">4</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">5</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">6</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">7</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">8</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">9</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">10</div>
</div>
```

Considero esta la solución más sencilla, pero pueden haber mejores soluciones que esta, pero requieren probablemente un amplio refactoring:

- Utilizar grillas para CSS y no aplicar Bootstrap a esta "grilla".
- Utilizar un framework enfocado a grillas.
- Cambiar la orientación de Flexbox de Bootstrap y realinear todo (complicado en mi opinión).
- Cambiar el display a `table` para el contenedor.
- Cambiar el HTML generado por Angular para que se ajuste a Bootstrap 4 (ver la respuesta de Willian).

EDICIÓN:

Gracias a la sugerencia de Mariano, vemos que no es necesario agregar CSS adicional, utilizando las clases "helper" de Bootstrap: `d-block` y `float-left`, pero sí es necesario modificar ligeramente el HTML generado por Angular.

```css
.titulo {
  height: 200px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.dato {
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row d-block">
  <div class="titulo col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">Titulo</div>

  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">1</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">2</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">3</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">4</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">5</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">6</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">7</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">8</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">9</div>
  <div class="dato col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 float-left">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, vas al origen del problema, que no lo tenía presente... Detalle: para evitar agregar un CSS que aplique a *toda* la clase de Bootstrap, se podrían usar las clases [d-block](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) y [float-left](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)... no?

Comment: Sí, sería más sencillo de hecho, pero quise mostrar el detalle en CSS "puro" y además hice la aclaración que no iba a modificar el HTML planteado por el OP en mi respuesta.

Comment: No sé cómo no he visto esta respuesta antes... acabo de borrar la mía porque era casi un clon de ésta. Por aclarar sobre como afecta que el OP esté usando Angular: si declara los CSS *dentro* del componente , el framework se asegura de que **solamente** afecte el HTML de dicho componente, no hay que temer que afecte a todo elemento que use esa clase de Bootstrap

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap trabaja con **primero filas luego columnas:**

Por la tanto primero creamos una fila que contendrá 2 columnas:
Dentro de la primera columna insertamos un **`div`** vacío, luego en la siguiente columna insertamos dos filas más que internamente tendrán 3 columnas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html lang="es">
 
<head>
<title>Titulo de la web</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
 
<body>
   
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      Div 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          Div 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          Div 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          Div 4
        </div>
      </div>
        
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          Div 5
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          Div 6
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          Div 7
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          Div 8
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          Div 9
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          Div 10
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          Div 11
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          Div 12
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          Div 13
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          Div 14
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          Div 15
        </div>
      </div>
  
</div>
   
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: completa tu respuesta que hace ese código?

Comment: Esa es la manera, muy bien.

Comment: El problema es que yo armo las cajas pequeñas dinámicamente con un ngFor de angular, por lo tanto dividirlas dentro de contenedores así como planteas no creo que sea factible, pero gracias.

Comment: Hasta donde entiendo, con esta grilla se pierde la parte responsiva del código de la pregunta. En el código del autor, se generan 3 columnas para `sm` y 4 columnas para `lg`. Con tu respuesta serían siempre 4 columnas.